# "Invalid paramenters" when trying to add Buildingblock in Word 2016

Tags: c#, error-handling, buildingblocks

I get Invalid parameters when I try to add a Building block in Word 2016.

The range is a cell in a table (the first cell in the last row). The Activedocument is the Template I would like to add the Building block to.

```
private void CreateNewBuildingblock(string sBuildingblockName)
{
  Document currentDocument = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument;
  Template templateFile = (Template) currentDocument.get_AttachedTemplate();
  currentDocument.Tables[1]
    .Cell(currentDocument.Tables[1].Rows.Count, 1)
    .Range.Text.Substring(
      0,
      currentDocument.Tables[1]
        .Cell(currentDocument.Tables[1].Rows.Count, 1)
        .Range.Text.Length - 2
    );

  Range rBuildingblockContent = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range;
  _ = templateFile.BuildingBlockEntries.Add(
    Name: sBuildingblockName,
    Type: WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeCustom1,
    Category: "Generals",
    Range: rBuildingblockContent,
    Description: "AV_Buildingblock",
    InsertOptions: WdDocPartInsertOptions.wdInsertParagraph
  );
}
```

Any suggestion / help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. The Range rBuildingblockContent is the content of a cell. A cell i Word contains "EndOfCell-sign" that cannot be part of the Range rBuildingblockContent. The solution is to select all the text in the cell except the "EndOfCell-sign".